# Searching for a group of words within the same sentence in R

Tags: r, regex, grepl

I am trying to search for a group of words within the context of the **same sentence**. For example, I am trying to find whether the words **`"not"`** and **`"sugar"`** both exist in the context of a **single sentence**

```
string = c(
"I do not like sugar. However, I like coffee.", 
"I like sugar. But I do not like coffee.")
```

Both texts  carry the words `"not"` and `"sugar"` but only the first text carries both words `"not"` and `"sugar"` in the **same sentence**. In the second text, `"not"` and `"sugar"` exist in different sentences.

I want to return `TRUE` for the first text and `FALSE` for the second text.

I have tried `grepl("not\\ssugar", string)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're attempt was very close.... This `[^\\.,!?:;]` allows any character except a punctuation mark between **like** and **sugar**.

```
string = c(
  "I do not like sugar. However, I like coffee.", 
  "I like sugar. But I do not like coffee.",
  "I do not like coffee. But I love sugar.")

grepl("not[^\\.,!?:;]*sugar", string)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible way, certainly not the most efficient, nor the easier to read (!)
Benefits though, it even provides you the sentence(s) that are TRUE.
I already isolated the set of words to be tested and code so that you are able to test for co-occurence of any arbitrary number of words.

```
string = c(
  "I do not like sugar. However, I like coffee.", 
  "I like sugar. But I do not like coffee.")

checkwords=lapply(string,
FUN=function(str,words=c("sugar","not"))
{
  sapply(strsplit(str,"\\.")[[1]],FUN=function(el){
    any(all(sapply(words,
           FUN=function(wd)grepl(wd,el))))
     })
})
# yes this can be a one line instruction...
checkwords

 [[1]]
     I do not like sugar  However, I like coffee 
               TRUE                   FALSE 

 [[2]]
              I like sugar  But I do not like coffee 
                     FALSE                     FALSE
```

And then you check for presence of at least one TRUE for every element of the initial vector `string`:

```
sapply(checkwords, any)
[1]  TRUE FALSE
```